# How use python selenium webdriver on flex container

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating some task with selenium webdriver for python.
I am curently on a selection by classname that is behaving strangely (only 4 of the 10 elements are found), I believe that is because the elements I am looking for are in a flexbox. Could that be it?
If so, I saw to handle flexbox one should use a add on on selenium, I saw this one https://code.google.com/archive/p/sfapi/downloads, buts it's for Java. What would you advice for python?

Thanks